# How to recognize the react-router-dom in the npm package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, yarnpkg

I have a component that creates a dynamic menu with a menu list. This list is taken from the backend. For this I create a dynamic menu with this list in my own npm package and use react-router-dom for routing.

There is the file path and url information to be used for the route at hand.

I want to use components from projects that use my package in "<Route component={...?...}". I couldn't figure out how to do it as I'm new to React. I don't know if such usage is correct. how can i solve?

my-package code :

CreateMenu.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
...
..
const [routers, setRouters] = useState([]);
...
...

const createRouter = (values, array) => {
    values?.forEach((element) => {
      if (element.children.length !== 0) {
        createRouter(element.children, array);
      }
      {
        element.data.url &&
          array((old) => [
            ...old,
            {
              url: element.data.url,
              componentPath: React.lazy(() =>
              import(`${element.data.path}`)) ,
            },
          ]);
      }
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    createRouter(moduleList, setRouters);
  }, [moduleList]);

...
...
   <Router>
      <div className="layout-content">
          {moduleList && (
            <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
              {routers?.map((router, index) => {
                if (index === 0) {
                  return (
                    <Route
                      key={`router${index}`}
                      path={router.url}
                      exact
                      component={router.componentPath}
                    />
                  );
                } else {
                  return (
                    <Route
                      key={`router${index}`}
                      path={router.url}
                      component={router.componentPath}
                    />
                  );
                }
              })}
            </Suspense>
          )}
        </div>
      </Router>
```

package.json:

```
"main": "dist/[name].js",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "public"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "chart.js": "3.3.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
    "sass": "^1.32.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

webpack.config.js

```
 output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].js",
    library: "react_framework",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
  },
...
...
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      ".js",
      ".jsx",
      ".ts",
      ".tsx",
      ".json",
      ".css",
      ".scss",
      ".esm",
      ".sass",
      ".less",
    ],
    modules: ["src", "node_modules"],
  },
```

main project:

App.js

```
...
import { CreateMenu} from "my-package";
...
...

return(
<MenuAndBreadcrum url={url}/>
)

...
```

Comment: Why are you trying to make a **npm** package?
Do you have a  problem with normal `jsx files` exporting the components?

Comment: I'm trying to make an npm package that I will use in multiple projects. I have multiple projects with the same structure and they will all be used the same way

Comment: I don't think you should be using npm packages for this but if you still want to...
Then I guess you will need to publish your package on npm and install it like other packages.